how to opt out of next js data cache
I have an app where the data is constantly changing, but with Next.js caching requests it's impossible for me to get updated data in time even do that data is updated in the database. I'm pointing to an external API, which means I'm not using the Next.js API router. I tried to set the cache header to 'no-cache' in the fetch like this :
 const response = await fetch(url, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache"

        },
        next: {tags : ['revalidate']},
      });

but it doesn't work
nb : im facing this error only when deploying to prod

Have you tried adding the cache: 'no-store' option? There are other options/approaches you can try listed in their official docs: Opting out of Data Caching

already tried that not working :/
